# How to publish a c# Windows Application that has a MySQL server connection

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, publish

I have been trying to find a way to publish my C# Windows Application that involves a database connection (MySQL). 
I want to be able to send this to my friends or even let others use it.

My problem is that I have no idea how to publish the app with the connection. Ive searched everywhere. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: The common way to accommodate a possible change in connection information is with program settings values.

Comment: You would need to find a hosting service that has the capability of SQL database connections. Windows Azure is popular, but there are many others.

Comment: @TestWell I currently have a hosting service that has a MySQL server + connection. Will this not work?

Comment: If they advertise support of SQL databases, I don't see why not. Which one are you using?

Comment: Is this a desktop application? If so, why not let the user configure their own MySQL server and have it hook into that? If you need something self-contained you probably want to use the [SQLite Library](http://sqlite.org/).